# HttpHeaders in webview with loadDataWithBaseURL()

Tags: android, webview

is any way to set custom header while using method `loadDataWithBaseURL()` in Android WebView?

My data is loaded from string as "data" as:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I need set 'Referer' for Youtube embed vidios.

Any idea?

Comment: Which api version  you are using ?

Comment: api version 8+,
but I am looking for all solutions.